# Where can I download/update to OS 10.10?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I am looking to update to OS 10.10. I am currently on 10.9.5.
Both the appstore and macupdate.com seem to only have 10.10.1-.5, all of which require already having 10.10 (which, as stated, I am looking for).

I need this update so that I can install a program required for work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Yosemite is still available for download, but [El Capitan is.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886) El Capitan is basically just Yosemite with some bug fixes, and has the same system requirements as Yosemite, so there's no real reason not to go to El Cap if you're already planning to go to Yosemite. (High Sierra is, obviously, even better if your Mac meets the requirements.)

Comment: You can get Yosemite if it’s already in your purchase history

Comment: @Tetsujin While that's true, it seems clear from the OP that it is not in their history.